# Access class attributes from an imported module through input arguments

Tags: python-3.x, class, import

I have a class named `TEST` in a configuration file `config.py` as follows:

```
# file config.py
class TEST():
    alpha = 0.05
```

and a file `run.py` from which I try to access attributes of the class `TEST` through input argument as follows:

```
# file run.py
import sys
import config

if __name__ == "__main__":
    conf = sys.argv[1]   # comes from input argument conf=TEST
    obj1 = config.TEST() # this works
    print(obj1.alpha)    # prints alpha variable 0.05
    obj2 = config.conf() # AttributeError: module 'config' has no attribute 'conf'
    print(obj2.alpha)
```

By running it as `python3 run.py TEST`, it gives attribute error in `obj2`, as it cannot convert the `conf` variable to `TEST` and access the class `TEST`. Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed by using the `getattr` from this thread:

[Calling a function of a module by using its name (a string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-of-a-module-by-using-its-name-a-string/3071#3071)

The code modification is as follows:

```
# file run.py
import sys
import config

if __name__ == "__main__":
    conf = sys.argv[1]             # comes from input argument conf=TEST
    obj1 = config.TEST()           # this works
    print(obj1.alpha)              # prints alpha variable 0.05
    obj2 = getattr(config, conf)() # 
    print(obj2.alpha)              # prints alpha variable 0.05
```

which by running it `python3 run.py` prints the desired.